# How does the Mysterious Books folder work?

Tags: macos, icloud, books

There is a magic folder which has all of my books which were manually added (not from the store). Moving books into this folder gets them on to my Books app on the iPad and the Mac.

The location is `~/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~apple~iBooks/Documents`.

The mystery is that I can use the above address using the Finder (<kbd>⇧⌘G</kbd>) but the path bar says that the location is `iCloud Drive › Books`. There is no way that I can find to navigate to this folder other than using <kbd>⇧⌘G</kbd>.

The other mystery is that if I try to access the folder from the shell, it says `No such file or directory`.

Can anybody explain how this works, and whether this is the only folder with this spooky behaviour?

I’m using an Intel iMac macOS 12.6 Monterey.

Comment: I have no trouble navigating to this folder with [vifm](https://vifm.info). However, in my case this folder does not contain all books added outside the store. It has only most recent ones accessed. It may or may not be related storage optimization i.e it might show only books that are locally on computer.

Comment: How are you accessing from the shell - note the path has a space in it so you might need to escape the space e.g. `ls ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/iCloud~com~apple~iBooks/Documents`

Comment: @mmmmmm Actually, I put the path inside quotes.

Comment: I don't think that works as "~" does not get expanded - use $HOME

Comment: @mmmmmm using `$HOME` does the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An issue here is how the shell interprests the path to the location.
The path you supply `~/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~apple~iBooks/Documents` has two issues.

1. it has a space in so you have to either enclose the path in quotes or escape the space.
2. It includes ~ If the path is in in quotes the zsh and bash shells will not expand ~ so use $HOME instead

So run the commands

```
ls ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/iCloud~com~apple~iBooks/Documents
```

or

```
ls "$HOME/Library/Mobile Documents/iCloud~com~apple~iBooks/Documents"
```

Comment: Thanks for the information about using the shell. I guess the real question is why isn’t this accessible from the Finder?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably safe to say most of the iCloud related folders have some 'spooky' behaviour. I suspect that xattr are used to specify a policy to Finder, and other UI components, on how to present them. eg to simplify that path into `iCloud Drive > Books` to use your example.

The Books folder can be navigated to via `System Preferences | Apple ID | iCloud | Manage (iCloud Storage, bottom right) | Apple Books | Show in Finder`. Some, but not all iCloud folders have this option.

[image]

To navigate to it on the command line, observe that `Mobile Documents` needs to have the space escaped (using <kbd>⇧⌘G</kbd> lets the Finder do the space for you), and that the ending `Documents` is a (sort-of, but not a Unix link) link back to your own `Documents` folder. So you would actually type:

```
cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/iCloud~com~apple~iBooks/
```

However, once there, there is not really anywhere else to go. The `Documents` subfolder just directs you back to your user's `Documents`.

Navigating to the folder via the System Preferences is the safest, though illogical way of doing the job I feel.

**Update macOS 14.1 (Sonoma)**

It seems the option to Show In Finder is no longer present in System Settings in Sonoma. Only the option to delete all books in iCloud.

Of course, this bit me when I was hoping to clear iCloud space, and deleted my local copies also. Cue a tortuous recovery on the command line once I'd mounted the relevant CCC snapshot. Also *interesting* to find on the command line, as of course Finder still won't see the `Mobile Documents` folder. Check the output of `mount` for the path, `/private/tmp/ccc_<SNAPSHOT>`.

Comment: I don’t have a `Show in Finder` in my preferences. Just `Delete all Files…`, which I choose not to put to the test.

Comment: I’ve tried the `cd` command with double and single quotes and that didn’t work. However, it did work (a) when I used `/Users/…/` and also when I moved `~/` outside the quotes, which suggests that the `~/` doesn’t work inside quotes. I guessed I learned a little more about bash here.

Comment: OK. You might want to update your question with the macOS version you are using, just to make sure everyone is singing from the same hymn sheet. The behaviour I describe is for 12.6 Monterey.

Comment: Same here. 12.6 Monterey. I’ll add it to the question.